# Force Git Pull to fail if a file is locked by another process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, configuration, pull

Sometimes if I have a solution open in Visual Studio when I pull from Git ( a common situation in this type of development environment ) it seems that Visual Studio will have certain files locked so that Git fails to overwrite them.

When that happens Git doesn't seem to care- it continues the pull and considers my local repository to be up to date. However as the files that it hasn't been able to write ( usually .csproj files ) have not been updated, nothing will build in Visual Studio or, worse, everything will build but some new quirky bugs will have been added or files are missing from the project causing unpredictable outcomes.

It would be more useful to me if Git was to fail and rollback the pull if there are files it cannot overwrite, rather than just ignoring it. I am guessing that this is configurable somewhere but I can't seem to find what to search for - can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation I have received is that this isn't really anything to do with Git- if Visual Studio has files open it will not lock them, but will then re-save them the next time you build ( or for other whimsical reasons of its own ) with the consequence that if it does this following a pull it will overwrite the changes that Git has successfully replaced, causing these types of problem.